# Why doesn't fill() change all the elements in the array?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I thought I could use fill() to change all the elements in the array and then get an image with a solid color. Instead I am getting bands of color.

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

arr3D = np.arange(500*500*3).reshape(500, 500, 3) 
print('arr3D shape = ' + str(arr3D.shape))                 
print('arr3D type = ' + str(type(arr3D)))
arr3D.fill(255)

Image.fromarray(arr3D, 'RGB').show()
```

This is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with how you were plotting the image, not with numpy.

You have to convert the array to uint8 before passing it to PIL:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

arr3D = np.arange(500*500*3).reshape(500, 500, 3) 
print('arr3D shape = ' + str(arr3D.shape))                 
print('arr3D type = ' + str(type(arr3D)))
arr3D.fill(255)
Image.fromarray(arr3D.astype("uint8"), 'RGB')
```